# How to make compiled c program executable output display on PHP webpage

Tags: php, shell, executable

I have a program that outputs data in command line.

MyProgram -d "02/02016/12:00-03/02/2016/12:00"

I am merely trying to display results from a compiled c program on Linux to the webpage. There are additional flags besides file(-f filename) and date(-d "datetime or datetime range").  There are other shell command flags available to the program but they have no impact on the display format of the text itself.

This results in output formated in command line similar to the following.  The actual results here is of little consequence.   It displays a list or records in a format similar to the following on the back end.

I am attempting to display the results below to the PHP front end web page.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<record_id_number_here> <date_stamp_tex><someflag_value><event_type_number>
<Some event status text information>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Things I've tried see test.PHP code below.  I am looking for just one working way.

test.php

```
<?php
    echo "ran as user:".exec("whoami");
    echo "test1<br />";
    echo exec("MyProgram -f TestLogBinaryFileDate");
    echo "test2<br />";
    echo system("MyProgram -f TestLogBinaryFileDate");
    echo "test3<br />";
    echo popen("MyProgram -f TestLogBinaryFileDate");
    echo "test4<br />";
    echo passthru("MyProgram -f TestLogBinaryFileDate");
    echo "tests calls complete";
?>
```

Each attempt to get the results from each of those functions did not stop PHP from continuing nor did it display any record data text that should have been.

MyProgram I've had even tried having the Apache user set as owner of the file compiled command line application and even moved the application into the the website we root directory where the webpage test.php resides.

Environments Linux ( fedora 22 or red hat Linux in the future),  Mariadb, PHP 5.6.8

I have no doubt I will be updating this with more information of what worked and did not work.

I've see posts that talk about safemode directory this does not work as safemode PHP was droped in 5.4 and deprecated in 5.3 therefore safemode should not be the problem.

Comment: It should be noted I've been able to use command line shell command php and been able to make this work in command line but it breaks when I try to put it into test.php.

Comment: I checked the PHP.ini for "disable_functions". No line in the file contains that line.  I found that at cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

Comment: Tried that as well no luck.    $test= exec_shell("MyProgram -f TestLogBinaryFileDate); echo $test;     Does not work.  I also tried pre tags as well no luck still blank.

Comment: @Dcross2017 - is `shell_exec` disabled in your php.ini? check `disable_functions ` directive. Also, check that PHP is not running in safe mode.

Comment: remember after making changes to restart apache/nginx/php-fpm or whatever you have.

Comment: also, make sure you know what you are doing in terms of security - exposing `shell_exec` / `exec` is usually turned off via php.ini to browsers for a good reason.

Comment: I do not think these are turned off as the command php  -r 'echo shell_exec("MyProgram -f TestLogBinaryFileDate");'        works and displays text in command line.  And echo exec('pwd'); echos out the full path of the test.php file to the browser successfully.   Is there some place perhaps PHP requires the executable to be located for this to work?

Comment: Yes, but usually, you will have 2 php ini files. One for cli, and one for the browser.

Comment: I'm looking at the /etc/PHP.ini  file .  This file was created when dnf installation of Apache and PHP occurred.  I was unaware there were usually two PHP.ini files.  I will try to find a second one.  If exec and she'll exec were disabled I would expect it to be more apparent and obivious such that pwd and ls -la commands would not work from the front end.

Comment: create a `phpinfo.php` file temporarily with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Open it in browser and Look for the php.ini directive and hopefully you will find the exact php.ini file that is being used by apache/mod_php